# PostgreSQLで特定の行を削除した時に全体のindexをズラすには？

Tags: postgresql, database

[image: 画像1]
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　-------------画像1-------------

画像1のようにindexが1,2,3,4という順番で並んでいて
2行目の列を削除すると

[image: 画像2]
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　-------------画像2-------------

画像2のようにindexが1,3,4となってしまうかと思うのですが

[image: 画像3]
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　-------------画像3-------------

画像3のように、
2のindexが削除されたら
3と4のindexを自動的に1つずつズレて
2と3にリネームされるようにしたいです。
そういった機能はPostgreSQLにはありますか？
無いとしたら、そういった機能を自分で作成しなくてはいけませんか？

［追記］
シーンの一覧画面を作る際、「scene_indexが5~10までのデータを取り出したい」
(5個ずつデータベースから取り出して、ページネーションを使って並べたい)
というような場合があり、カラムを用‌​意していないと取り出しにくいのではないか‌​なと思い
このような質問にさせていただ‌​きました。
scene_indexが歯抜け‌​状態になっているデータベースからでも
指‌​定した位置の前後5個のデータを取り出す、という処理が出来るのであれば
それでも良い‌​かと思うのですが、そういった方法があるかも分からなかったた‌​め
このような質問をするに至っています。

Comment: `scene_index` は primary key ですか？

Comment: 今はscene_indexをprimary keyに設定していますが、scene_indexをprimary keyじゃなくすればズラすことが出来るのであれば、別のprimary keyを作ろうと考えています。

Comment: どちらかというと primary key の方が(NOT NULL and UNIQUE 制約という点で)都合が良くて、[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48f14/8) の様にすればできるのですが、懸念点があります。実際には primary key を別個に作る方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: `scene_index`カラムを用意する意義ってあるんでしょうか？ 読み出したときに連番を振れば済みそうに感じます。

Comment: シーンの一覧画面を作る際、scene_indexが5~10までのデータを取り出したい、というような場合があり、カラムを用意していないと取り出しにくいのではないかなと思って、このような質問をさせていただきました。scene_indexが歯抜け状態になっているデータベースからでも、指定した位置の前後5個のデータを取り出す、という処理が出来るのであればそれでも良いかと思うのですが、私はデータベースの知識が浅く、そういった方法も分からなかったため、こういった質問をするに至っています。

Comment: 実際にやりたいことがあるなら質問に追記してください

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scene_index` の値の順序が分かれば良いのであれば view を使う方法もあるかと思います。具体的には、以下の様にして view を作成します。

```sql
# CREATE VIEW scene_view AS SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY scene_index) AS nth, * FROM scene;

# select * from scene_view;
 nth | scene_index | accountd |  scene_name  | created_date 
-----+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------
   1 |           1 |      120 | 初ステージ     | 2013-06-22
   2 |           2 |       59 | てすと        | 2012-12-22
   3 |           3 |   301217 | 作れたかな？   | 2015-02-03
   4 |           4 |      982 | あああ        | 2014-08-22
(4 rows)

# delete from scene where scene_index = 2;
# select * from scene_view;
 nth | scene_index | accountd |  scene_name  | created_date 
-----+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------
   1 |           1 |      120 | 初ステージ     | 2013-06-22
   2 |           3 |   301217 | 作れたかな？   | 2015-02-03
   3 |           4 |      982 | あああ        | 2014-08-22
(3 rows)

# insert into scene values(0, 0, 'ゼロ', '1970/1/1');
# select * from scene_view;
 nth | scene_index | accountd |  scene_name  | created_date 
-----+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------
   1 |           0 |        0 | ゼロ          | 1970-01-01
   2 |           1 |      120 | 初ステージ     | 2013-06-22
   3 |           3 |   301217 | 作れたかな？   | 2015-02-03
   4 |           4 |      982 | あああ        | 2014-08-22
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 4):

> scene_indexが5~10までのデータを取り出したい

であれば、`scene_index`の**値**で絞り込むのではなく[LIMITとOFFSET](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/7.3/user/queries-limit.html)を使用して5行目から6行を表す

```
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 5
```

を指定することで実現できますので、`scene_index`の値にこだわる必要はないかもしれません。